# How to call a method from the same class in Java?

Tags: java, class, oop, methods

How can I call getDummy from main? I need this so I can pass dummy to a method in another class.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        private int dummy = 0;
    }

    public int getDummy() {
        return dummy;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well as `getDummy` is an instance method, you'll need an instance of `Test` to call it on... do you have such an instance? Note that currently you're trying to declare the `dummy` field *inside* the `main` method - that won't work. Please work on the layout of your code as well - indent it properly when posting. Most IDEs can help with that.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
public class Test {

   private int dummy = 0;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Test test = new Test();
      int dummy = test.getDummy();
   }

   public int getDummy() {
      return dummy;
   }
}
```

I assume `private int dummy = 0;` is a property (variable) of `Test` class. Calling a `non-static` method from a `static` method is not allowed. You create an instance of your class in the `static` method and can call any of its `public` methods.

Comment: *"there's no meaning to private variable in a method"* this is not true and does not help the OP. Please remove that or make your point more clear.

Answer (score 1):

***getDummy*** is an instance method so you need  the instance

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Test t = new Test();
        t.getDummy();
    }
```

and this belongs to the class

```
private int dummy = 0;
```

---

your final code could look like>

```
public class Test {
    private int dummy = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.getDummy();
    }

    public int getDummy() {
        return dummy;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be declare target object, and initialization, then you can use `getDummy()`, or you can modify `getDummy()` method to static .

Answer (score 0):

sry, my english very bad, but i think i can help you. first, you create a public variable out of main,  in you code, you only create a local variable. next, in your main, you type : "getDummy();". good luck

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and
[How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=how+to+answer)

Answer (score 0):

**For any new learner.**

the basic concept to understand here is about the **static** and **not static** components and its scope.

When a method is declared **static**, it created one method per class, and after compilation, any instance of the class will use the same method.

```
static void staticMethod(){}
```

**static** methods of a class can be directly called with class reference

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        T.staticMethod();
    }
```

When a method is defined as **non static** (without static keyword) , after compilation , each instance will have a separate copy of the method and will operate independently of parallel calls to same method from different instances of the class.

```
void nonStaticMethod(){}
```

**non static** methods of a class can be called only with instance of the class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        T testObj = new T();
        testObj.staticMethod();
    }
```